# How to add a button in menubar for enable and disable proxy?

Tags: applescript

I'm rookie in AppleScript, I need to create and add new icon to menubar and then execute a command from terminal to activate my socks proxy

What I have done so far :

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi on"
end tell
```

As I mentioned I need : 1) Create a toggle button in menubar 
2) Be able to on and off Socks proxy

Any idea ?
Thnx

Comment: Unless you are planning on implementing an NSStatusItem, the simplest way would be to enable the Script Menu (from the Script Editor preferences) and put your utilities in that via the ~/Library/Scripts folder.

Comment: thnx for your reply, I know that, but it was better if I could put it as button in menubar.

Comment: @Freeman — while this is doable, it's overkill. You'd need to create a cocoa-applescript app (that's needed both to create the status bar item and to handle the call-back from the button): all of that to run one line of code: `do shell script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi on"`.

Comment: @TedWrigley, thnx Ted, button is not important. I just need an option for that or sub-menu in menubar is it possible?

Comment: As @red_menace said, enable the script menu — which puts a status bar menu in your menu bar, just like you wanted — write a script that says what I wrote above, and put the script in ~/Library/Scripts. The script will be visible in the script menu bar item, and can be run from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who helped me, I want to share this and hope this comes in useful for you.

I wrote a simple code and put it into this path `~/Library/Scripts`

Then in `Script Editor.app` under `Preferences` tab I enabled `Show Script menu in menubar`

```
set socksStatus to do shell script "networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxy Wi-fi | grep Enabled"

if (offset of "Yes" in socksStatus) = 0 then
    do shell script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-fi On"
    display notification "Proxy Enabled !"
else
    do shell script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-fi Off"
    display notification "Socks disabled"

end if
```

as you can see, when you run the code it enable the proxy and if you run it again it will be disable.

Have a great day !